# Why is AutoMapper not mapping from NPoco dynamic object to entity?

Tags: c#, automapper, npoco

When I do an NPoco fetch

```
var products = db.Fetch<dynamic>(sql).ToArray();
```

and then try to map it with AutoMapper

```
Mapper.Map<Product[]>(loc)
```

The resulting `Product` does not have any of the expected values even though

- The names and case of the column names in `sql`, the `NPoco.PocoExpando` instances in `products`, and the `Product` class, and they all match.
- The values in the expando are correct for each column.
- The setters in `Product` are public.

The [AutoMapper documentation](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Dynamic-and-ExpandoObject-Mapping) suggests that I'm doing everything correctly. Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my call to `Mapper.Initialize` I set `IMapperConfigurationExpression.CreateMissingTypeMaps` to true. It seems that doing this interferes with the dynamic mapping.